# Get value from one table, insert it in query of other. How to?

Tags: php, mysql

This one is a bit more complex and can't be done by innerjoin or something similar. I already got help with it, but I could not figure it out. Here is what I am doing: I need to get a row of text from one table and insert it into the query of another, when getting the results. In one I save `('2','3','4')` which are the links to the IDs of the maintable. So in order to get them, I have to pull them first out of the table, insert them into the php, where I then pull the related rows out and save them into xml. Here is the important part:

```
$name = ($_GET["name"]);
$query =  "SELECT Favorites FROM $table_id2 WHERE Name = $name";

while($favoritesstring = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query, $dbconnect))){
$favoritestringresult = $favoritesstring['Favorites'];
} 

$string = stripslashes($favoritestringresult['Favorites']);

$query = "SELECT Name,Comment,ID FROM $table_id WHERE ID in " .$string;

$dbresult = mysql_query($query, $dbconnect) or die(mysql_error() . ' Query: ' . $query);
```

Comment: This is kind of a tangent, but you should never just take unsanitized user input (like you do from GET) and use it in queries. Please see http://xkcd.com/327

Comment: Haha, thanks, that was funny. And also I use mysql_real_escape_string - I just did not put it up there with :)

Comment: It's not quite clear from the code you've provided, but I looked at your previous question and it seems as though you are storing a list of IDs as the "Favorites" column. I think you would do well to normalize your tables, perhaps storing favorites in their own table which will allow you to take advantage of JOINing or using a sub-query.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Warning:**
>
> Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)?
>
> Instead, you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) should give some details about deciding which API to use. For PDO, here is a [good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Consider the following database setup:

```
-- This contains the elements: books, videos, albums.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entries` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `comment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

-- This contains what our users favourited.
-- row_id: row identifier index
-- name: the name of the user to search for
-- entry_id: the id of the entry we search for, this will
--           make our JOIN relation towards entries.id
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `favorites` (
    `row_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    `entry_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`row_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Put in some arbitrary data of course:

```
INSERT INTO `entries` (`id`, `name`, `comment`) VALUES
    (1, 'Foobar', 'Bazqux'),
    (2, 'Barbaz', 'Quxfoo');

INSERT INTO `favorites` (`row_id`, `name`, `entry_id`) VALUES
    (1, 'someguy', 1),
    (2, 'someguy', 2),
    (3, 'person', 2);
```

We will need a basic script to query our database:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("database");

$result = mysql_query('SELECT entries.id, entries.name, entries.comment
    FROM entries
    INNER JOIN favorites ON entries.id = favorites.entry_id
    WHERE favorites.name = "' .mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']). '"');

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
    var_dump($row);

mysql_close();
```

If we give `$_GET['name']` the value of `someguy`, our result will be:

```
array (
  'id' => '1',
  'name' => 'Foobar',
  'comment' => 'Bazqux',
)
array (
  'id' => '2',
  'name' => 'Barbaz',
  'comment' => 'Quxfoo',
)
```

While with the value of `person`, we will only get:

```
array (
  'id' => '2',
  'name' => 'Barbaz',
  'comment' => 'Quxfoo',
)
```

The trick lies in the `INNER JOIN`. Our search pattern, the `WHERE` clause tells the database that we search for the `favorites.entry_id` where the `favorites.name` is the input. From there, the `JOIN` makes the link between the two tables extending our search. `INNER JOIN` means that **only** those rows will be returned whose `entries.id` equals with `favorites.entry_id`. And of course we fetch the fields listed in the `SELECT` statement. *After all, this is what we told the database to do.* [Some more, visual explanation.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

And from here, inside the `while(){}` construct, you can do anything you want with the retrieved data.

Instead of fetching all the IDs and then inserting it into an `field IN (value1, value2)` statement, `INNER JOIN` makes use of the relational structure of MySQL, which results in better performance and maintainability.

And as I have [said in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=4808611#4808611) while we were discussing a similiar matter with another person:

> The complexity you can build up with MySQL sometimes can be beyond imagination. The bottom line is that at first you need to make sure your database is modelled properly. After that, it's just a matter of how you link one field to another. Tools like phpMyAdmin, LibreOffice Base or Microsoft Access can be a great help with the graphical interface to model relationships between keys.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your two queries, this could be done as:

`"SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name, t1.Comment FROM $table_id t1 LEFT JOIN $table_id2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.Favorites WHERE t2.Name = $name"`

I'm `LEFT JOIN`ing here because *I* don't actually know the relationship between `$table_id` and `$table_id2`.

Comment: Yes, well, the problem is, that I have to get the value from table2 first, because there are all the IDs in it, that I want to get displayed from table1.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but it came up with an error: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: Here is the full code, it would be appreciated if you or someone else could take a look at it. The values are slightly different from the ones in my question: http://pastebin.com/Gm7BgH7Y

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible solutions for this. One is by using subquery:

```
SELECT  name, comment, id
FROM    table_id
WHERE   ID in   (
                    SELECT  Favorites
                    FROM    table_id2
                    WHERE   Name = $name
                )
```

and another which is more efficient is by using `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Name, a.Comment 
FROM    table_id a 
            INNER JOIN JOIN table_id2 b 
                ON a.ID = b.Favorites 
WHERE b.Name = $name
```

Comment: Yes, well, the problem is, that I have to get the value from table2 first, because there are all the IDs in it, that I want to get displayed from table1.

Comment: exactly, did you see the first solution? the subquery there ***selects all the favorites id and then the return value will be the parameter of the upper query***. on the second solution, it will join the two tables having the same id from the first table and the favorites id on he second table but will only show all the rows that has the value of `$name`

Comment: Hey, thank you. I also tried both of your solutions, but for some reason I come up with the same error:  Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: Here is the full code, it would be appreciated if you or someone else could take a look at it. The values are slightly different from the ones in my question: pastebin.com/Gm7BgH7Y